# Where can I find Jesus Christ?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

Father Maxi has sent me off to find Jesus.

I found him once already, doing a piss-poor job of 'hiding' in the Church, but now he's run off again, and I need to find him again. Where is he hiding?

Comment: Without the reference to the game I was shocked for one second about that question.

Comment: "Guys, your heart is the first place everybody looks. I'm not going to hide there. Give me some credit, okay?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He is in the church again, behind the lectern. Turn the spotlights so that they both point at the cross, and hit the light switch by the door on the right. You'll see his shadow on the cross, so go behind the lectern and look for the action button indicator, and you've found him.